# Column name in data frame goes back to numeric

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, as.date

Hi I'm trying to load some dates as column names of my data frame but they will only appear as numbers (11595 for example) even if I'm forcing them with as.Date

Is there another way to do this? Thanks!

```
dates  <-  seq(as.Date("2000-1-1"), as.Date("2018-10-1"),  by="3 months") -1
d.test <-  data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 8, nrow = 8))

for (i in 1:8) {

  colnames(d.test)[i] <- as.Date(dates[i], "yyyy-mm-dd")
}
```

Comment: `names` or `colnames` or `dimnames` can only be character strings. Your date gets converted to a number and then to a character string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set dates with as.character, also avoid for loops when not necessary.  See ?colnames or ?rownames, the value assigned should be a character vector

```
dates  <-  seq(as.Date("2000-1-1"), as.Date("2018-10-1"),  by="3 months") -1
d.test <-  data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 8, nrow = 8))
colnames(d.test) <- as.character(dates)[1:ncol(d.test)]
```

Answer (score 0):

See `?colnames`. Values for column names should be a character vector and will be coerced using `as.character()`. Column names are just labels, not variable types.